# Excel VBScript running Batch and passing arguments

Tags: excel, batch-file, vbscript

I am trying to call a batch file with EXCEL VB SCRIPT with arguments which are variables storing values from Excel Cells.  here's the code. With my existing code, its not passing the variable value just the variable name to Batch which is expecting these arguments.

**How can I pass the actual variable value to Batch?**

**EXCEL VB CODE**

```
jserver = Excel.Worksheets("Data_Sheet").Range("A2").Value
ip = Excel.Worksheets("Data_Sheet").Range("B2").Value
port = Excel.Worksheets("Data_Sheet").Range("D2").Value
user = Excel.Worksheets("Data_Sheet").Range("E2").Value
pass = Excel.Worksheets("Data_Sheet").Range("F2").Value

Call Shell("C:\Package\BIN\account.bat jserver ip port user pass")

MsgBox "J SERVER-->" & jumpserver & Chr(13) & "IP-->" & arip & Chr(13) & "PORT-->" & port & Chr(13) & "USER-->" & aruser & Chr(13) & "PASSWORD-->" & arpass, vbInformation
```

**Message Box Shows Correct Values**

**Batch is written like this -->**

```
@echo off
ECHO "CREATING ACCOUNT"

REM DECLARE VARIABLES

set jserver=%1%
set ip=%2%
set port=%3%
set user=%4%
set pwd=%5%

ECHO %jserver%
ECHO %ip%
ECHO %port%
ECHO %user%
ECHO %pwd%
```

**Value Printed:**

```
"CREATING ACCOUNT"
jserver
ip
port 
user 
pass
```

Comment: you are passing the literal in your Shell command. Concatenate the variables as you did in the Msgbox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to build your command by concatenation, don't use the [wrong](http://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/gg278870.aspx), but the [correct](http://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/gg264104.aspx) operator:

```
>> jserver = "JS"
>> ip = "IP"
>> port = "PORT"
>> user = "USER"
>> pass = "PASS"
>> cmd = "C:\Package\BIN\account.bat " & jserver & " " & ip & " " & port & " " & user & " " & pass
>> WScript.Echo cmd
>>
C:\Package\BIN\account.bat JS IP PORT USER PASS
```

and don't copy untested code from the internet:

```
>> cmd = "C:\Package\BIN\account.bat " + jserver + " " ip + " " + " " + port + " " +user + " " + pass
>>
Error Number:       1025
Error Description:  Expected end of statement
```

Did you spot the missing & before ip? If not, start to research for less error-prone ways to build strings from parts (Join, Replace in templates, printf/Format alike functions).

Comment: Thanks Ekkehard.Homer .... I did not use the last answer as such.  But I need a lil help in Function...How do I exit the value from below Functions??                                             Function AddQuotes(value As String)

If InStr(value, " ") > 0 Then
        value = """" + value + """"
End If
  
End Function

Comment: @ArunGanesh - look here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/20272474/603855 for an example of returning a value from a function in the VBScript way: by assigning the value to the function name (variable).