# Combining a directory and a batch file to execute in one line

Tags: batch-file, vbscript

How can I combine a directory(say C:\Program Files\dir1) which is in a variable and comes from a property in installshield  and a batch script test.bat to execute in a single line (C:\Program Files\dir1\test.bat)??? I was trying the below but in vain.

```
    dim shell
    dim strInstallLocation, strbatch
    set shell=createobject("wscript.shell")
    strInstallLocation = """C:\Program Files\dir1"""
    strbatch = strInstallLocation &"""\test.bat"""
    shell.run strbatch
    set shell=nothing
```

I get a type mismatch property. I am new to this vbscripting. Please help even if it is a basic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The (first) parameter to .Run should be quoted to help the shell to parse the file specification correctly. For that you can use:

```
Function qq(s) : qq = """" & s & """" : End Function
```

To build a file specification from a folder/path and a file name, the FileSystemObject provides the .BuildPath method. It should be used instead of home grown string operations (assuming you have an FSO in goFS):

```
>> sFolder = "C:\Program Files\dir1"
>> sFile = "magic.bat"
>> sFSpec = goFS.BuildPath(sFolder, sFile)
```

All together now:

```
>> sCmd = qq(sFSpec)
>> WScript.Echo sCmd
>>
"C:\Program Files\dir1\magic.bat"
```

Comment: Horner, could you be more specific on my entire code. Sequenced code as in my question helps along with variables. Thanks for the help in advance